# Why does keras skip saving checkpoint?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

Hello I have this problem that states that keras will skip saving checkpoints because val_acc is missing.

```
RuntimeWarning: Can save best model only with val_acc available, skipping. skipping. % (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning)
```

I have the monitor set to val_acc and I have validation_data set to test_set (you will see in the code) but still doesn't save checkpoints.

CODE:

```
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.3,
                                  horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('TRAIN_SET',
                                                 target_size = (input_shape, input_shape),
                                                 batch_size = batch_size,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('TEST_SET',
                                            target_size = (input_shape, input_shape),
                                            batch_size = batch_size,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(WEIGHTS_PATH, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='max')
model.fit_generator(training_set,
                    steps_per_epoch=len (training_set.filenames)//batch_size,
                    epochs = 60,
                    validation_data = test_set, 
                    validation_steps = len (training_set.filenames)//batch_size,
                    callbacks = [checkpoint])

model.save('model.h5')# creates a HDF5 file 'model.h5'
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try changing the monitor value to `val_accuracy`. Source: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33163

Comment: Thank you sir it works now hahaha. Didn't knew a simple thing causes such an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to sir techytushar for the hint of changing val_acc to val_accuracy. It seems to have been an issue when I updated anaconda. 
Source: github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33163

Comment: hey, please don't call me sir, just happy to help.